# coffeescript - Array filtering not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, coffeescript, filtering

I'm trying to get an array with only elements that have the property of background-image, however, my code isn't working and i'm not sure what's wrong.

```
elements = document.getElementsByTagName("*")
[].filter.call elements, (el) =>
  if el.currentStyle
    return el.currentStyle['backgroundImage'] isnt 'none'
  else if window.getComputedStyle
    return document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(el,null).getPropertyValue('background-image') isnt 'none'
```

Comment: *How* "doesn't it work"? On what page do you apply it? What is the expected outcome, what happens instead?

Comment: If I log out elements before and after the filter call, the results are the same.

Comment: Oh, what did you expect, you're not returning the filtered array anywhere, try something like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/Rqd22/

Comment: @EvanWard: `filter` does not alter `elements`. It does return a new array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [javascript documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter),

> The `filter()` method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

So you need to store your filtered array before using it:

```
elements = document.getElementsByTagName("*")
filteredElements = [].filter.call elements, (el) =>
  if el.currentStyle
    return el.currentStyle['backgroundImage'] isnt 'none'
  else if window.getComputedStyle
    return document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(el,null).getPropertyValue('background-image') isnt 'none'

// filteredElements is your new array with the filtered elements.
```